# Swift -- Custom tableview cell with buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitableview

In my app I would like to have custom cells in my table view that displays a row of buttons that may display all buttons or fewer depending on data. The cell looks like this:

[image]

Some of the buttons may not apply to every cell so some cells may look something like this.

[image]

What are some ideas on how to structure this so only the buttons that are required show? If I hide a button the space remains. I would like all the buttons to start at the left and only show the ones that apply with no space in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a `UIStackView`. They are wonderful for managing sets of evenly spaced objects like buttons.

Put a stack view in your table view cell, and then have your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method remove any leftover buttons from the last time the cell was used and add the ones you need. You could even get fancy and manage an array of recycled buttons in order to avoid creating/destroying buttons each time a cell comes into view.